# Apache Beam File IO - Watch for file modifications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a dataflow component which watches for new files in my folder. Along with emitting new files, I would want it to emit if any of the existing files gets modified too. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
PCollection<FileIO.ReadableFile> tfConfigYamls = pipeline.apply(
                "ReadConfigYamls",
                FileIO.match()
                        .filepattern("gs://folder/*.yml")
                        .continuously(Duration.standardMinutes(2), never()))
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches());
```

If I place a new file in the folder, my dataflow would emit those changes. But if I modify an existing file, it doesn't.  What should I do to make FileIO.match watch for file modifications?

Comment: I'm not sure modifications are tracked, only new files. https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html

Comment: You could always implement an extra layer of logic that checks if any of the hashes of the files change, which could then trigger further analysis

Answer (score 0):

What you are using `FileIO.match()`

> Produces a collection of matched resources (both files and
>   directories) as MatchResult.Metadata.
>
> ...
>
> Returned MatchResult.Metadata are deduplicated by filename. For
>   example, if this transform observes a file with the same name several
>   times with different metadata (e.g. because the file is growing), it
>   will emit the metadata the first time this file is observed, and will
>   ignore future changes to this file.

So in this case, you will never be able to see if there is a change in the files, because you will get only the first record of `MatchResult.Metadata` for filename, the additional metadata is ignored by this method.

**[EDIT]:** `FileIO.matchAll()`

> Resources are not deduplicated between filepatterns.

So similar behavior that `FileIO.match()` when using a single filepattern.

You could use `FileIO.readMatches()`

> Converts each result of match() or matchAll() to a FileIO.ReadableFile
>   which can be used to read the contents of each file, optionally
>   decompressing it.

Once you get the `FileIO.ReadableFile`, you can implement the logic to verify if the file has been modified. One option is to use `FileIO.ReadableFile.getMetadata()` and compare this MatchResult.Metadata with the one from `FileIO.match()`

[Docs FileIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#match--)

[Docs FileIO.ReadableFile](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.ReadableFile.html)

As an alternative option you can use the FileIO.Match object directly, and explore if you get the desired behavior with an override or setting your own configuration.

[Docs FileIO.Match](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.Match.html)